# Excel Pivot Table: how to combine data from two tables?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Let's say we have two tables:

```
ID (FK) | Col1
1       | A
1       | B 
2       | C

ID (PK) | Col2
1       | AA 
2       | BB
```

I need to get following result in report (Pivot Table):

```
ID     | Col2 | Col1
[-] 1  | AA   | A
       |      | B
2      | BB   | C
```

Comment: Why a PivotTable specifically? It looks like you could achieve this with a simple formula added to table 1 to get the data from table 2 (VLOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH, XLOOKUP, dealer's choice really)

Comment: We would prefer to use Pivot Table because it allows to expand/collapse denormalized/repeating values.

Comment: What have you tried and what research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a Power Pivot data model. Power Pivot is a game changer for building complex pivot tables in Excel.
It's a standard Microsoft Add-in since Version 2013 (Windows).

On the MS Website it's defined how to [combine two tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/use-multiple-tables-to-create-a-pivottable-b5e3ff48-2921-4e29-be15-511e09b5cf2d).

Comment: This is not yet an answer. Links are not answers. You must include all of the actual answer here in this post, and leave a link for attribution or further research only.